# Could cobalt make a good sword? and what knownk alloy would be the closest to it?

Tags: weapons, materials, urban-fantasy

The setting is semi modern urban fantasy where there are mercenaries with the task of slaying monsters on the unpopulated areas, steel is the first metal to go when it comes to making weapons on large scale or for those who don't have the money for better materials. But because almost everyone and most of monsters can potentially bend fire, spit corrosive fluids etc. Making so the best weapon material that one those mercenaries could use must be better than classic spring steel in those cases; My best bet is to introduce cobalt weapons, I've read about the properties of cobalt and somewhat they match, but I'm not that sure of how good it would be for weapons like swords.
Did a bit of research and found Elgiloy which is an alloy that's used for springs and from what I know spring metal works well especially for swords.
But I'm not sure of how good would that work.

Comment: What does cobalt do which [marine stainless steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_316L_stainless_steel) doesn't?

Comment: Wolfram or Titanium?

Comment: @AlexP Cobalt can mechanically work at high temperatures

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY not sure about wolfram but titanium isn't good for edges

Comment: @Dawnstarwatcher I've been always a fan of stabby-longy-distanty-thingy like arrows or spear rather than swords.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Maybe its not the answer I'm seeking but thanks for the tip, it would help for things like pole arms

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY titanium is a bit soft for edges and a bit light for bashing, and tungsten isn't nearly as tough as steel making it a less-than-awesome choice for melee weapons even when sensibly alloyed (and its a right pain to forge, too). The availability of either also implies enough modern technology to provide for guns, which might be a more sensible choice all round...

Comment: I'm a big fan of using [Javelin-style missiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FGM-148_Javelin) or [Gatling-style machine gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minigun) or [Grenade machine guns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mk_19_grenade_launcher) against those pesky fire-breathing, acid-spitting, smart monsters. If you let them close to bayonet range, the survivors are gonna be sore the next day.

Comment: @user535733 what an interesting version of a witcher would be that

Comment: Why do you need metals at all?  (Quite apart from the fact that it's a lot harder to get useful amounts of cobalt &c than plain old iron, of which there's an abundance in any urban fantasy.)  You just go to something like the Aztec macuahuitl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macuahuitl

Comment: The short answer, and questions like this come up a lot here, is that steel is THE best material we know of to make a sword out of. Anything else you make it out of either won't be as sharp, or won't be as impact-resistant, or (usually) both. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?page=4&tab=Relevance&q=sword

Answer (score 6):

The main advantage of using iron alloys for making swords is that the properties of the material can be locally tuned to improve the global performance of the blade.

When you look at how a blade works, you want to have:

- a hard surface, to be able to resist the impact with the target
- a tenacious core, to be able to withstand the solicitations imparted by the blow

Now, a single alloy can be hard and brittle or tenacious and softer, and you see that you will have to compromise too much to make a good sword.

Using iron based alloys instead one can use I.e. quenching or carbon hardening to have a hard surface while maintaining a tenacious core, dramatically improving the performances of the blade.

From what I see, cobalt and its alloys are generally hard and resistant to high temperature, but that alone would make the cobalt blade brittle. And you don't want a sword that shatters on impact, don't you?

Comment: why would high temperature resistance make it brittle?

Comment: @Dawnstarwatcher, hardness is usually coupled to brittleness. Temperature resistance has nothing to do with it.

Comment: sorry misread that part, I understand that the material being brittle is a problem, but is hardness proportional to how brittle it is? or there's a property related to it?

Comment: @Dawnstarwatcher yes, basically hardness = brittleness in that the properties that make something 'hard' (in this case, able to hold a sharp edge) make it unable to flex under impact, which prevents distribution of force across a greater volume/area of the blade. Steel is great because it can be hard in one place and softer elsewhere in a single piece which lets you mix and match your physical properties in a way that most other materials don't permit.

Answer (score 3):

In additional to its brittleness, the oxidation products of cobalt are toxic.  Not in a "poisoned sword that keeps on poisoning" sort of way, more in a "use this thing long enough, and you'll get deathly ill and may die" manner.

Now, there are cobalt *alloys* (with iron, which makes them steels) that work well, but in general, you want a carbon steel for weapons.  It can be hardened by heat treatment, and tempered to make the hard edge and tough core that makes a sword durable.  Adding a little molybdenum helps a lot for toughness, while cobalt can help with corrosion (not as much as chromium and nickel, though -- those go into stainless).

And contrary to the movies, there are no acids that will eat away your blade in the blink of an eye.  Get a splash of concentrate nitric, sulfuric, or hydrochloric acid on the blade, and if you don't just let it sit there and eat away at the surface you'll get local darkening and etching (the kind that brings out the grain structure in a polished surface) -- not wholesale destruction.

Comment: I should had put it more clear on the corrosion part, never intended it to be like in the movies, but more like how long it would take for it needing some maintenance. The parts of the toxic byproducts makes sense but wouldn't it help having it protected from it? coating it with oil, people do it with steel why wouldn't it happen with cobalt.

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely be hard to do.

just finding the material is going to be way harder than finding iron.

I found this through Wikipedia, definitely worth checking out this graph
[image: Elemental Abundance]

You can see that Iron (Fe) has about 10^5 atoms for every 10^6 atoms of Si, whereas Cobalt (Co) has about 10^1 atoms per 10^6 atoms of Si.

1,000 Atoms of Fe for every atom of Co.

Let's talk melting point now.

Iron has a melting point of 1,538C. Cobalt has a melting point of 1,495C. that is only about a 40-degree difference. Therefore we will say it has no impact on anything essential.

Cobalt has a density of 8.86g/cm^3 whereas Iron has a density of 7.874g/cm^3. Let's remember that casting cobalt means you're probably going to have to anneal it as well.

after all of this work, you'd think it would be worth it right?

Absolutely not.

Cobalt is extremely brittle so if you decide to try to sharpen it we can assume it would just shatter into a million pieces.

**Shortened Answer:**

**You'd be putting in too much time and effort to A) Mine cobalt, B) Melt it, C) anneal it, and D) Sharpen it, just to be presented with a heavy blade that would slowly poison you over time. Not worth all that effort if it's gonna kill you.**

Comment: Please link to where you got the image from. Is it showing Earth abundances?